# Fill shape of contour

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to pre-process an image for OCR. How do I fill in the contours of the text to make it more readable for the algorithm[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vylVw.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

do *not* apply Canny. OCR expects filled letters, not outlines.